# JSON key/value pair plus count

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, json, jquery

I need to return json data from the server, which can be used on the client side and I am not sure the best way to format the json data.

So basically, What is the best way to format the json data to include:

1. key/value pairs so they can be looped through at clientside (loop via jquery),
2. a count of the number of id/value pairs which can be used at clientside for other purposes (used via jquery).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example JSON file and an accompanying HTML file with jQuery for reading from it.
`data.xml`

```
{
    "revision": "1.0",
    "name": "Membership List",
    "members": [
        {
            "id": "12",
            "name": "Matt Santino",
            "age": "37"
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "name": "Marco Svorinsky",
            "age": "59"
        },
        {
            "id": "6",
            "name": "Jim Green",
            "age": "38"
        },
        {
            "id": "27",
            "name": "Xiao Pang",
            "age": "22"
        }
    ]
}
```

`index.html`

```
<html>
  <head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="<JQUERY FILE>"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $.getJSON('data.xml', function(data){
        $.each(data.members, function(index, value){
          $('#info').append(value.name+'<br />');
        });
      });
    });
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="info">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I edited my post to show you a little better how it would work. If you have any more question just ask.

Answer (score 0):

I think this articles will explain what you are looking for: 
http://geekswithblogs.net/michelotti/archive/2008/06/28/mvc-json---jsonresult-and-jquery.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you'd want to format your json.

[
    {
        "key": "value"
    },
    {
        "key2": "value2"
    }
]

I usually use JSONLint.com to check and see if the JSON i'm creating on the server side is valid JSON.

Comment: How would I access this on clientside `json[i][0]` for `key` and `json[i][1]` for `value`?